# How long we can keep our flutter app installed on iOS for testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

How long we can keep our flutter app installed on iOS for testing?

I want to install a flutter app on iOS for my personal use. So I want to know whether we can keep the app installed forever.

Comment: For `test purpose` upload app to `TestFlight`; App will expire after `90 days`